# Can a non-regular language have a regular grammar?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Basically the title. I am supposed to find a regular grammar for the language that produces palindromes. This is all I have right now:

```
S -> 1 | 0 | ε
```

Since it should be a regular grammar, I can't write 0S0 or 1S1. But then I don't know how I should even continue with this...

Comment: The language generated by any regular grammar is regular.

Comment: Ah yes, I just realized this. Therefore it should be impossible to find a regular grammar for this particular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular grammar generates a regular language – the existence of a regular grammar for the language of palindromes would imply the language to be regular. However, it isn't, hence a regular grammar for it cannot exist.